# Vlookup data from another worksheet, if the Vlookup is true, concatenate/jointext from certain cells in sheet, return to working sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

=Lookup_concat(if(vlookup(CELL$,IMPORTRANGE("File URL","Tab Name"),Column Numner,false)=Yes))

--> I want to now join text from a specific cell from the same sheet as my Vlookup Import sheet and return the combined text into the worksheet I'm waking in. What do I do next?

Comment: Do you want Google Sheets or Excel?

Comment: @ACCtionMan Excel please

Comment: And what text are you looking to concatenate? Do you want multiple columns as part of the VLOOKUP or is it some static text? Might need to update your question with an example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An example is say I have a sheet of data where 5 companies are listed. Company 1, Company 2, Company 3, Company 4, Company 5. I want to look up and see if Company 4 in another sheet is open for operation on a certain date. If say the look up equals "Yes" they are open in column A in another sheet. Return the hours they are open by textjoin or concad Column B (Open time) and Column C (close time). Those combine value should be by return value to my current sheet.

Comment: Maybe =IF(VLOOKUP(CELL,IMPORTRANGE("Sheet URL","TAB!$A:$I"),5,false)="Yes".....then return jointext or concad from another cell. Is this posisble?